# I want to output 4 byte signed integer type value

Tags: perl, integer

I am using a Perl script.

I want to use 32 byte signed integer form like c language.

For example, if I add 1 to the integer value, I want to output it as shown below.

```
my $val = 0;
while(1){
   print $val++;
}
-------------------------------
The desired result.
0
1
2

.
.
.
2,147,483,646
2,147,483,647
-2,147,483,648
-2,147,483,647
-2,147,483,647
.
.
.
```

But I do not know how to use 4byte signed integer value.

Comment: Incrementing a 32-bit signed integer `2,147,483,647` is undefined behaviour in C. You aren't guaranteed to get `-2,147,483,648`. In fact, your program could get a different number once in a while, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell Perl what size of integers you want to use.<sup>[1]</sup>

But that doesn't appear to be what you want. You appear to want a counter that wraps from `2,147,483,647` to `-2,147,483,648`.

You'll have to do it the same way as you would in C:

```c
int32_t i = 0;
...
/* Can't use use ++i because incrementing 2147483647 is undefined behaviour */
i = i == 2147483647 ? -2147483648 : i+1;
```

or

```
int32_t i = 0;
...
/* Can't use use ++i because incrementing 2147483647 is undefined behaviour */
i = (int32_t)((((int64_t)i)+1) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

---

1. Perl uses three numerical storage types:

   - signed integer of size `ivsize`
   - unsigned integer of size `uvsize`
   - floating-point number of size `nvsize`

   You can get The size of each of type (in bytes) as follows:

   ```
   perl -le'use Config qw( %Config ); print $Config{ivsize};'
   perl -le'use Config qw( %Config ); print $Config{uvsize};'
   perl -le'use Config qw( %Config ); print $Config{nvsize};'
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -V:ivsize
   perl -V:uvsize
   perl -V:nvsize
   ```

   Not only is the size of these types fixed when `perl` is compiled, you can't select which of these types `perl` will use to store a value. Furthermore, `perl` will automatically convert from one type to another when an overflow would occur. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083776/589924))

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html). Pack your variable into an `unsigned int`, then unpack it to a `signed int`.

```
my $val = 2147483646;
for(my $i=0;$i<4;$i++){
   my $uint = pack('I', $val++); 
   print unpack('i', $uint);
}
```

Note, that:

> (This 'integer' is _at_least_ 32 bits wide.  Its exact
>             size depends on what a local C compiler calls 'int'.)

so it might be better to use `N` or `V` instead of `I`.

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/24r5rv)