# printf difference between c and perl

Tags: c, perl, printf

In C:

```
printf ("%u", 17860374324089702869);
```

prints "3336554965" (this is the answer I want!)

In perl, the same line of code prints "17860374324089702869".

How can I get perl to produce "3336554965" from "17860374324089702869".

My gut says this is 64-bit vs 32-bit issue, but it does not appear that the perl statement is doing anything at all to the number.

Comment: Perl does not has an integer max bound

Comment: [Perl documentation for format strings](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) says "`%u` - unsigned integer, in decimal". Nothing about 32-bit.

Comment: Re "*I would have thought that %"u" meant a 32-bit unsigned*", It doesn't even mean that in C.

Comment: Yes, but I would have thought that "%u" meant a 32-bit unsigned, but apparently not. So then, the question is, how can I convert the long unsigned to a 32-bit unsigned.

Comment: But it works fine in C!  I meant "%u" of course.

Comment: Only by accident. I'm fairly sure your example has undefined behavior. Casting to `(unsigned int)` would be fine, of course (but would not necessarily give you a 32-bit result; for that you want `uint32_t`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, `printf` `%u` takes an `unsigned int`. Whether that is a 32-bit or 64-bit value or something different entirely depends on your C implementation. The standard only requires that `int` be at least 16 bits wide. (Since the value you're passing in your example doesn't fit in an `unsigned int`, I'm pretty sure your code has undefined behavior: You're not passing an `unsigned int` to `%u` as it expects you to.)

In Perl, `%u` converts its argument to an unsigned integer. The width of this integer depends on how Perl was compiled; it is normally either a 32-bit or 64-bit type. You can query the configuration details for your perl by running `perl -V:uvsize` (the size of Perl's unsigned integer type in bytes) and `perl -V:uvtype` (the corresponding C type).

If you want to explicitly truncate your value to 32 bits, the easiest way is probably to apply a bit mask:

```perl
use constant { UINT32_MAX => 0xffff_ffff };
print 17860374324089702869 & UINT32_MAX, "\n";
```

Then you don't really need `printf` either.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such unsigned 32-bit integer in Perl. The 17860374324089702869 become 3336554965 in C is because unsigned 32-bit integer has a range 0 to 4294967295, when there's overflow occur, the integer would came up from the lower bound and vice versa

e.g

```
unsigned int a = 4294967296 // will be 0 because unsigned integer upper limit is 4294967295
```

So you only have to module it with 4294967296 because there's 4294967296 numbers from 0 to 4294967295

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

printf "%09u", 17860374324089702869 % 4294967296
```

Comment: Re "*17860374324089702869 become 3336554965 in C*", Not always, even. `int` has to be at least 16-bit in size, you could get entirely different (smaller, larger) results on different machines/compiler. (And that's assuming this is defined behaviour.)

Comment: Technically, there's no overflow of unsigned integers in C.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not about Perl's `printf`/`sprintf`, but about how Perl stores integers and passes integers to functions. As mentioned in other responses, there is no 32-bit integer type in Perl.

Basically, you need to strip the half of your 64-bit integer to make it 32-bit. To do this, just use binary `&`:

```
perl -e 'printf("%09u\n", 17860374324089702869 & 0xffffffff);'
3336554965
```

Here, the `&` operation leaves bits of the lower 4 bytes unchanged, but sets bits of the higher 4 bytes to zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The C language has a plethora of numeric data types (and sizes). Perl has 3 type of data -- "[scalars, arrays of scalars, and associative arrays of scalars](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)",

In Perl, scalar values are polymorphic, so the value *17860374324089702869* can be treated as a string or a number, depending on how it is used. When used in a printf statement, it treated as the number 17860374324089702869 and printed as such.

In C, an unsigned integer is treated as an integer number in a range specified by the word size on the architecture you are compiling the program for. You should have received warning when you compiled. When I compiled the above statement with -Wall, here is the warning I got:

warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__int128’ [-Wformat=]

[See this post discussing the maximum integer value that can be count to in Perl.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081972/maximum-integer-in-perl)