# How to prevent that a floating point divistion turns into integer devision by measuruing time intervals in seconds of type float

Tags: perl, datetime, floating-point, division

I try to calculate a transfer rate for a bulk copy process using perl version 5.20 under Freebsd 12. I get strange results, because values in a sub-second interval are always zero, despite of using a float division to get a fractal second duration entry.

**Details:**

For the measurement I use DateTime::Hires and abstracted the time mark & difference in two sub routines called `markTime` and `diffTime`. To see what is going one each step is printed.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.20.1;
use warnings;
use strict;
use bigint;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep nanosleep);
use DateTime::HiRes;
use Scalar::Util::Numeric;

# Set the total size of an object 
my $ttlSize = 1E3;

# Set the start time
my $startTime = &markTime('START');

# Sleep 12500 µs
usleep(12500);

# Calculate the elapsed time
my $runTime =  &diffTime($startTime);

# Calculate the rate in Bytes per second
my $rate =  $ttlSize/$runTime;

# Print it
print "RATE: $rate Bytes/s\n";

# Routine to set a timestamp 
sub markTime () {
    my $prefix =  shift;
    $prefix ='NOW' if not $prefix;
    my $now =  DateTime::HiRes->now;
    print"MARK.$prefix: ",$now->strftime( '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.%N' ),"\n";
    return $now;
}

# Routine calc the difference
sub diffTime () {
    my $start = shift;
    # Calculate the duration
    my $now  =  &markTime('DIFF');
    my $dur  =  $now - $start;
    my $nano =  $dur->in_units('nanoseconds');

    # Original dateTime duration is integer
    print "DT.DUARTION: ",$nano," ns  IS.INT: ",
        Scalar::Util::Numeric::isint($nano),"\n";

    # Calc values for mano, micro, milli and seconds
    my $math_ns  = sprintf("%e",$nano);
    my $math_mus = sprintf("%e",$math_ns/1.0E3);
    my $math_ms  = sprintf("%e",$math_ns/1.0E6);
    my $math_s   = sprintf("%e",$math_ns/1.0E9);
    # Show the calculations
    print"MATH: ",$math_ns," ns\n";
    print"MATH: ",$math_mus," µs\n";
    print"MATH: ",$math_ms," ms\n";
    print"MATH: ",$math_s," s\n";
    # Check if the stuff ist float
    print "TIME.SECS: ", $math_ns*1.0E-9,
        " TIME.NANO: "   ,$math_ns,
        " IS.FLOAT: "  ,Scalar::Util::Numeric::isfloat($math_ns),"\n";
    return $math_s;
}
```

The result shows, that the sub-second float value for `runtime` is "cutted" by the division and the transfer rate becomes INF, despite of using a float divistion operation.

```
MARK.START: 2019-12-12-10-12-33.954870000
MARK.DIFF: 2019-12-12-10-12-33.968422000
DT.DUARTION: 13552000 ns  IS.INT: 1
MATH: 1.355200e+07 ns
MATH: 1.355200e+04 µs
MATH: 1.300000e+01 ms
MATH: 0.000000e+00 s
TIME.SECS: 0 TIME.NANO: 1.355200e+07 IS.FLOAT: 1
RATE: inf Bytes/s
```

What do I've to do, to get a correct value of 0.013552 for the `$runtime` variable?

Dump values:

```
---NANO---
SV = PVNV(0x8029cf9f0) at 0x8031c6408
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,NOK,POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 13574000
  NV = 13574000
  PV = 0x8031ab5d0 "13574000"\0
  CUR = 8
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1

---MATH_NS---
SV = PV(0x802cb8900) at 0x8031c64e0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x8031ab0f0 "1.357400e+07"\0
  CUR = 12
  LEN = 16
  COW_REFCNT = 2

---MATH_NS/1E9---
SV = PV(0x802d18b50) at 0x802f19bb8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x8031d97c8
  SV = PVHV(0x800a8a560) at 0x8031d97c8
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,SHAREKEYS)
    STASH = 0x8016910d8 "Math::BigInt"
    ARRAY = 0x80323cdc0  (0:7, 2:1)
    hash quality = 62.5%
    KEYS = 2
    FILL = 1
    MAX = 7
    Elt "value" HASH = 0x7025df17
    SV = IV(0x803162b60) at 0x803162b70
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (ROK)
      RV = 0x801acca08
      SV = PVAV(0x800a894d8) at 0x801acca08
        REFCNT = 1
        FLAGS = (OBJECT)
        STASH = 0x801692e70 "Math::BigInt::Calc"
        ARRAY = 0x802d3bb18
        FILL = 0
        MAX = 0
        FLAGS = (REAL)
        Elt No. 0
        SV = IV(0x800b19ae8) at 0x800b19af8
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
          IV = 0
    Elt "sign" HASH = 0xc9f40697
    SV = PV(0x802cb8aa0) at 0x8031c6078
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
      PV = 0x8017af0f0 "+"\0
      CUR = 1
      LEN = 10
      COW_REFCNT = 1
  PV = 0x8031d97c8 ""
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 0
```

**Correction of diffTime with Math::BigFloat**

So I worked it out, that in the program `use bigint;` (now invoked in the example) is the trouble maker and will have effects on all divisions. The work around is:

```perl
sub diffTimeBigFloat () {
    my $start = shift;
    # Calculate the duration
    my $now  =  &markTime('DIFF');
    my $dur  =  $now->subtract_datetime_absolute($start);
    my $nano =  $dur->in_units('nanoseconds');
    # Original dateTime Duration
    print "DT.DUARTION: ",$nano," ns  IS.INT: ",
        Scalar::Util::Numeric::isint($nano),"\n";

    # Calc values for mano, micro, milli and seconds
    my $math_s  =  Math::BigFloat->new(sprintf("%sE-9",$nano));
    print"MATH: ",$math_s," s\n";
    print "TIME.SECS: ", $math_s, 
          " TIME.NANO: ", $math_s*1E9,
          " IS.FLOAT: " ,Scalar::Util::Numeric::isfloat($math_s),"\n";
    return $math_s;
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate your results, but `$math_ns/1.0E9` should be `$nano/1.0E9` and `return $math_s` should be `return $nano/1.0E9;`. There's no reason to convert the numbers to strings!

Comment: Note that `$now - $start` won't work as expected if the difference is a minute or more (because `in_units` it doesn't have enough info to convert minutes into seconds or nanoseconds, because not all minutes have 60 seconds). You should be using `$now->subtract_datetime_absolute($start)`

Comment: Yes, I guess that too but  I cast  `$nano` explicitly to a `float` using the `sprintf..` way, to see whats wrong. Unfortunately as you see TIME.SECS: in  `TIME.SECS: 0 TIME.NANO: 1.355200e+07 IS.FLOAT: 1` produced by `print "TIME.SECS: ", $math_ns*1.0E-9,  " TIME.NANO: "   ,$math_ns,  " IS.FLOAT: "  ,Scalar::Util::Numeric::isfloat($math_ns),"\n";` is zero, despite of being a `float`.

Comment: Re "*I guess that too but I cast the $nano explicitly to a float using the sprintf*", No, `sprintf` produces a *string*

Comment: No it is a float ...`IS.FLOAT: 1`

Comment: No, it's a definitely a string. `isfloat` doesn't return the type of the value or values in the scalar.

Comment: Any way `print "TIME.SECS: ", $nano*1.0E-9, " TIME.NANO: "   ,$nano, " IS.FLOAT: "  ,Scalar::Util::Numeric::isfloat($nano*1E-9),"\n";`  produces `TIME.SECS: 0 TIME.NANO: 13541000 IS.FLOAT: 0`;

Comment: It still works as a string, because `/` doesn't care if the number is stored as a signed int, unsigned int, float, string (UTF8=0) or string (UTF8=1). The whole premise of your quesiton (that there is some kind of integer division) is false.

Comment: So I repeat, You shouldn't be performing these useless stringifications, and `$now - $start` should be `$now->subtract_datetime_absolute($start)`

Comment: Ok,  what ist the the right cast of $nano to produce a valid float result, because `$nano * 1E-9` or `$nano/19E` produces 0?

Comment: Please add `use Devel::Peek; Dump($nano); Dump($math_ns); Dump($math_ns/1.0E9)` and provide the output

Comment: Please, the interval that is tested is below one second, I tested `$now->subtract_datetime_absolute($start) ` with no effect.

Comment: Right, it won't make a difference for very small durations, but it's the correct tool to use in conjunction with `$dur->in_units('seconds')` or `$dur->in_units('nanoseconds')`

Comment: So `my $math_s  =  Math::BigFloat->new(sprintf("%sE-9",$nano));`  with `print "TIME.SECS: ", $math_s, " TIME.NANO: "   ,$math_s*1E9, " IS.FLOAT: "  ,Scalar::Util::Numeric::isfloat($math_s),"\n";` produces the correct results`TIME.SECS: 0.013604 TIME.NANO: 13604000 IS.FLOAT: 1`

Comment: In the Question at the end.

Comment: Somehow, the value is being truncated because it's being replaced with a Math::BigInt object (as if `use bigint;` was used), yet you didn't show Math::BigInt or bigint(.pm) being involved. Is the program providing the output you get the exact one you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use bigint;` effectively causes `1.0E9` to be replaced with `Math::BigInt->new(1.0E9)`.

Furthermore, Math::BigInt overrides division when at least one of its operands is a Math::BigInt object. The override cause the result to be a Math::BigInt object.

`use bigint;` can therefore have large effects at a distance. As such, I personally find `use bigint;` far too magical. I'd much rather use `Math::BigInt->new(...)` where appropriate rather than having `use bigint;` convert all my numerical constants into Math::BigInt objects.

But you went the other way. Not only are you using `use bigint;`, you are using it when you obviously don't want its effects. At the very least, use `no bigint;` inside of `diffTime` so the numerical constants in that sub aren't automatically wrapped into Math::BigInt objects.

```
use bigint; 

# bigint isn't used by DateTime::Duration
my $nano = do { no bigint; 13552000 };

say $nano/1E9;                        # 0
no bigint;
say $nano/1E9;                        # 0.013552
```

But like I said above, I recommend avoiding `use bigint;` alltogether in favour of explicitly creating Math::BigInt objects where appropriate, which is not at all in your case.

```
my $nano = 13552000;
say $nano/1E9;                        # 0.013552
```

---

If you need to deal with Math::BigInt objects for whatever reason, and you need to perform floating point operations on them, the solution is to convert the Math::BigInt object into an ordinary scalar or a Math::BigFloat (or Math::BigRat) object.

One can convert a Math::BigInt object into an ordinary scalar using `$x->numify`. This may overflow if the value is too large.

One can convert a Math::BigInt object into a Math::BigFloat object using `Math::BigFloat->new($x)`.

```
use bigint; 

use Math::BigFloat;

# bigint isn't used by DateTime::Duration
my $nano = do { no bigint; 13552000 };

say $nano/1E9;                        # 0
say $nano/(1E9->numify);              # 0.013552
say $nano/Math::BigFloat->new(1E9);   # 0.013552
```

Don't use `sprintf` as you did. That will cause a needless precision loss.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation, it is more I've expected. I think I've to write the code, to handle two things. One the one hand I need scalars that can address `uint64` to hold the file sizes and the total sum of them (up to some TByte). So I've to `use bigint;`. in some way. On the other hand there is these fine granular  statistic stuff of the transfer rate with some MBytes/s. that can be placed in the `{no bigint ...}`.  Thanks again

Comment: Perl is usually built with 64-bit ints. You can check using `perl -V:uvsize`. If this gives 8, 64-bit unsigned ints are used. If your Perl doesn't support 64-bit ints, just build one that does in your home directory instead of using Matg::BigInt. It's actually quite easy.

Comment: Even if your Perl doesn't support 64-bit ints, it probably supports floats with 53 bits of precision. (`perl -V:nvsize` returns `8`.) Such a Perl can accurately store the numbers up to 9,0007 T. See [Maximum integer in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25081972/589924)